# UIButton 's touchUpInside will trigger even when the touches already out the bounds of button?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit

I found the UIButton 's touchUpInside will be triggered even when my finger is moving out of the bounds of button slightly.
And if I want the touchUpInside not be called when the finger moves out of button . How to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can't change this behavior. You would have to write your own button-like view.

Comment: I have tried a UIView with TapGestureRecognizer to do this , but the TapGestureRecognizer will also be called outside the bounds in this situation. Seems the only way to do this is judge the UITouch's position , it the position is out of bounds. just ingore it ?

Comment: OK, I found a more easy option to do it : just Add a PanGestureRecognizer to the view, and do nothing in the PanGestureRecognizer's callback . The successfull recognization of pan gesture will make the other touch event cancel . So the TapGesture's callback will not called when your finger moves out of the button's bounds